# DefaultView in .NET

Tags: .net, rowfilter, defaultview

I want to know what the 2 following statements do

```
var dvOrder = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
gridTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CompanyName < 'I'";
```

Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Lastly,Is  ds.Tables[3].DefaultView[0]; same as  dvOrder = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView .?

Comment: Looks like C# code to me.

Comment: Yes I am certain about that. But what  does DefaultView, DefaultView.RowFilter , DefaultView[0] do when used with Dataset(ds) ,as shown in above exmaple   .Could you please let me know .

Comment: Thanks @UweKeim. For your Previous Response

Answer (score 0):

Check MSDN before asking here. Questions like yours tend to get a lot of down votes because of lack of effort.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks alot  TiagoBrenck